# I tried to install express generator but I am getting this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm-install

```
$ npm install -g express-generator

npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)

changed 10 packages, and audited 10 packages in 5s

3 low severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Comment: That's not an error, it's a WARNing. The package should still work fine.